# Trying to compute Lebesgue outer measure of irrationals by constructing a cover

Tags: general-topology, lebesgue-measure, irrational-numbers

It is known that to compute the Lebesgue outer measure $\lambda^*$ of irrationals $\Bbb{I}$ we make use of the following property:

$$\lambda^*(\Bbb{I}) +\lambda^* (\Bbb{Q}) = \lambda^* (\Bbb{R})$$

and noting that since $\Bbb{Q}$ has zero measure being a countable union of singletons and using countable subadditivity of $\lambda^*$, we thus conclude that $\Bbb{I}$ has full measure and more generally $\lambda^*([a,b]\cap \Bbb{I}) = b-a$

However, in order to better understand what features of uncountable sets controls the value of its Lebesgue outer measure, I tried to compute  $\lambda^*([a,b]\cap \Bbb{I})$ by constructing an open cover to exclude all rationals (Without loss of generality, and for ease of writing down the enumeration of rationals I use, we consider $\lambda^*([-1,1]\cap \Bbb{I})$ and the general result can  be obtained by appropriate translation and scaling of the interval)

I first give an enumeration of the rationals within $[-1,1]$ as follows:

$S=\{(p, q) \in \Bbb{N}^2 - \{n\in \Bbb{N} : (n+2,1)\} : \pm \frac{p}{q} \in \Bbb{Q} \land \text{lcm} (p,q)=pq\}=\{0,1,-1,\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},-\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},-\frac{2}{3}, \frac{1}{4},-\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4},-\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{5},-\frac{1}{5}, \frac{2}{5},-\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{5},-\frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{5},-\frac{4}{5},...\}$

and then construct my open cover $C$ in stages (which for the later stages, I abbreviated the union by using n-tuples). Each later stage splits up the interval from the previous stage by the next two rationals in the order given by $S$:

\begin{align}
C_0 & =(-1,1)\\
C_1 & = (-1,0) \cup (0,1) := (-1,0,1)\\
C_2 & = (-1,-\frac{1}{2}) \cup (-\frac{1}{2},0) \cup (0,\frac{1}{2}) \cup (\frac{1}{2},1) := (-1,-\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{2},1)\\
C_3 & = (-1,-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{3},0,\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2},1)\\
C_4 & = (-1,-\frac{2}{3},-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{3},0,\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3}‌​,1)\\
C_5 & = (-1,-\frac{2}{3},-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{3},-\frac{1}{4},0,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3}‌​,1)\\
C_6 & = (-1,-\frac{3}{4},-\frac{2}{3},-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{3},-\frac{1}{4},0,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3}‌​,\frac{3}{4},1)\\
C_7 & = (-1,-\frac{3}{4},-\frac{2}{3},-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{3},-\frac{1}{4},   -\frac{1}{5},0,\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3}‌​,\frac{3}{4},1)\\
C_8 & = (-1,-\frac{3}{4},-\frac{2}{3},-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{3},-\frac{2}{5}, -\frac{1}{4},   -\frac{1}{5},0,\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{4},\frac{2}{5},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{3}‌​,\frac{3}{4},1)\\
C_9 & = (-1,-\frac{3}{4},-\frac{2}{3},-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{3}{5},-\frac{1}{3},   -\frac{2}{5},-\frac{1}{4},-\frac{1}{5},0,\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{4},\frac{2}{5},\frac{1}{3}, \frac{3}{5},\frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{3}‌​,\frac{3}{4},1)\\
C_{10} & = (-1,-\frac{3}{4},-\frac{2}{3},-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{3}{5},-\frac{1}{3},   -\frac{2}{5}, -\frac{1}{4},-\frac{1}{5},-\frac{1}{6},0,\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{4},‌​\frac{2}{5},\frac{1}{3}, \frac{3}{5},\frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{3}‌​,\frac{3}{4},1)
\end{align}

and therefore: $C = \lim_{k\to \infty}C_k$

By construction, $C$ will exclude all rationals. We can also show that the lengths of all the intervals will converge to zero by considering the following subsequence $T$ of $S$

$T=\{n : \Bbb{N}-\{0\} : \pm \frac{1}{n}\} \cup \{0\} = \{-1,-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{3},-\frac{1}{4},-\frac{1}{5},-\frac{1}{6},...,0,...\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2},1\}$

and the difference between consecutive terms (except $0$) given by $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ which tends to zero as $n \to \infty$, and that any elements of $S$ will lie somewhere between the elements  of $T$ thus the lengths of intervals with those endpoints will be $\leq \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ for some $n \in \Bbb{N}$

However the above conclusion result in a couple of confusing issues:

1. $\Bbb{I} \cap [-1,1]$ is neither open nor closed (in the open interval topology of $\Bbb{R}$), but $C$ must exclude all rationals by construction (because $S$ enumerates all the rationals in $[-1,1]$, including troublesome limit of endpoints like $0$). This brought into question on what those progressively getting smaller intervals in $C$ are containing.
2. Every interval, no matter how small, must contain uncountable many irrationals and countably many rationals. But $C$ excludes all the rationals, so that would mean those intervals contains only irrationals. But this contradicts with the fact that no uncountable subset of irrationals are open nor closed (though finite union of irrationals can be closed as finite union of singletons (which are closed sets) are closed) thus no open interval can contain only irrationals
3. If the intervals tends to zero, it means their infimum length will be zero as $C$ only has countably many of them (thus by countable subadditivity of $\lambda^*$ this sums to zero). But we know this is incorrect as using the standard proofs in paragraph 1, we would conclude $\lambda^*([-1,1]\cap \Bbb{I}) = 2$ and not zero measure.

> Since $C$ must exclude all rationals by construction, what exactly are the intervals in $C$ are containing in order to be consistent with the issues raised in 1,2,3? Does $C$ actually contains intervals?

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing, or why you expect the limit to be an open set. But in any case, writing $\lim_{k\to\aleph_0}$ is making me cringe.

Comment: To clarify a bit. I tried to construct a cover for the irrationals by starting with $(-1,1)$ and then progressively split up this interval at rational values in the order shown in $S$. For any finite stage, however large, there are finite number of intervals.Approaching the limit the length of each interval seemed to converge to zero. However since the limit case don't always hold despite it holds for all natural numbers, and also given those inconsistency 1,2,3 I noticed if I accept the conclusion,I am suspecting the limit case don't contain intervals,but I am not sure how to demonstrate that

Comment: I also edited away the $\aleph_0$. Initially I wrote that so that the limit stages won't go uncountable. In theory the notation could be formalised by $\lim_{k < \alpha}$ (since $S$ is a well ordering of rationals, thus can be indexed by ordinals) where $\alpha$ is a countable (limit) ordinal, but I might be wrong

Comment: Any non-empty open subset of $\Bbb R$  contains rationals...... And your statement that no uncountable subset of irrationals is closed is FALSE. Let $S$ be open with $S\supset \Bbb Q$ and $\lambda (S)<1.$ Then $T=\Bbb R \setminus S$ is closed and is disjoint from $\Bbb Q$ and has non-zero measure so it cannot be countable.

Comment: To add on what @Daniel said, if there were no uncountable closed subsets of irrationals, then the inner measure (given by approximations from below with compact subsets) would have to be $0$ and thus imply (along with the result you want to prove here) that the irrationals are not measurable...

Comment: As for the ordinals you mention, $\aleph_0$ is a cardinal. Context is key. $\omega+1\neq\omega$, but $\aleph_0+1=\aleph_0$. And while you could certainly write $\lim_{k\to\alpha}$ and even $\lim_{k\to\aleph_0}$, this is a question of suitable context.

Comment: @AsafKaragila . BTW, an old Q in American Mathematical Monthly was " A student asserted that every uncountable set of reals contains a closed uncountable subset. Is this true?".... Just for fun.

Comment: @Daniel: Assuming choice, no. But without choice, consistently yes.

Comment: @Daniel: Also, if CH fails, then trivially no.